# Wrap divs around input with directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to know if it possible, and in the case of yes how do this.

I've an input in my form like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dirinput"
       placeholder="Placeholder"
       translate
       translate-attr-placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
```

I wish to, around this input, wrap divs to manage the label and errors if there's (like showing a string in case of error).
I need also to be able to put directives at the input element.

At the moment I've to write all this code for each input

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group label-static"
                 ng-class="{ 'has-error': relatedForm.first_name.$invalid && relatedForm.first_name.$dirty,
                 'has-success' : relatedForm.first_name.$valid }">
                <label for="input-first_name"
                       class="control-label" translate>
                    FIRST_NAME
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       id="input-first_name" name="first_name"
                       placeholder="First name"
                       ng-model="relatedCtrl.data.first_name"
                       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"
                       required autofocus>
                <p class="help-block"
                   ng-if="relatedForm.first_name.$error.required" translate>
                    ERR_FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you can see there's a lot of "duplicate" code, and I wander if it possible to avoid this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you can, and probably should use a directive, however you can't really "wrap" directives around other objects (as far as I know). Instead, create a directive and pass in parameters to populate the dynamic data (such as input names, model names etc.)

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`transclude`** feature of Angular directives:

```
myModule.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-transclude.html'
  };
});
```

In `my-transclude.html`:

```
<div class="wrapper>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

In your HTML:

```
<my-input>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dirinput"
         placeholder="Placeholder"
         translate
         translate-attr-placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
         ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
</my-input>
```

Reference: [Angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Of course, you can use `template` instead of `templateUrl` directly without the additional HTML file but `templateUrl`'s a good practice to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create directive with [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) that wrap your input.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5ea34pce/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

});


myApp.directive("wrapExample", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude:true,
    scope: {
      proccess: "=",
    },
    template:'<div><label>I\'m before wrapped label</label><div ng-transclude></div><div>I\'m after wrapped div</div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <wrap-example>
    <input value="input"  />
    </wrap-example>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add custom directives to the input element? like a custom validation of the data

Comment: Sorry, i'm don't know)